# In dotnet mvc 5, how to inject a service into a view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

In **dotnet core mvc**,i can inject a service into a view by using **@inject** directive,but how to do this in **dotnet mvc 5**.It seems that there is no **@inject** directive in **mvc 5**.

Comment: What are you wanting to do? Why do you need to inject an service into a view? You should just be using view models containing the data you need in the view.

Comment: No, that feature is from AspNet Core, MVC 5 doesn't have support for injection in views

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to hide some element in a view for users who don't belong to some groups.In dotnet core mvc, i can do like this:
'
@@inject MyAuthorizeService authService;

@@if (authService.InThisGroup("GroupA")){
    <div>only show for users in GroupA</div>
}
'

Comment: Then simply use a view model with a property `bool CanViewXX` and set its value in the controller where it belongs (or you can always pass it to the view using `ViewBag`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke e...how to input at symbol in the comment. sure,it can be done by ViewBag or property.But i think it is not  elegance enough。

Comment: What? `@if(Model.CanViewXX) { <div>.....</div> }` is a lot better than your use of `inject`

Comment: `@if(Model.SomethingForA != null) { <section/> }` ?

Answer (score 8):

## ASP.NET MVC 5 doesn't have `@inject`

This keyword only exists in ASP.NET Core.

### Work-around using `@model`

However you can still inject a dependency in the controller and from the controller pass it to the model. `@model` and `@Model` can be used freely in the razor page/view.

***MyController.cs:***

```cs
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(IMyDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        View(new ViewModel
        {
            Dependency = _dependency
        });
    }
}
```

***Razor.cshtml:***

```html
@model ViewModel

@if (Model.Dependency.CanView)
{
    <!-- Put the code here -->
}
```

It also means you can put a `IServiceProvider` in the model and resolve directly in the view. However, in terms of separation of concerns, it's not the ideal.